# Polymer 1.0 body elements in Grails GSP

Tags: grails, polymer

I see examples using this:

```
<body fullbleed unresolved>
```

and also this

```
<body class="fullbleed unresolved">
```

Are these lines equivalent?

Because in Grails using the first method causes the exception:

```
Caused by
[views/layouts/main3.gsp:15] Expecting '=' after attribute name (fullbleed unresolved).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a Grails issue. It probably only supports official/known boolean attributes (attributes without values) on DOM elements but not on custom elements.

AFAIK in Polymer 0.5 mostly attributes were used but Polymer 1.x tends towards classes. I don't know if the attribute selectors are still supported.
iron-flex-layout only supports fullbleed classes (see https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-flex-layout/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=fullbleed)